# SVG support in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, html, svg

I'm working recently with svg. I'm developing with ASP.Net and I added SVG code in my aspx site. I'm facing a problem with a svg method: createSVGPoint().

The problem is when I run my project, Microsoft Visual Studio reports that  createSVGPoint() is not supported. I'm new to this technology and I wonder what the problem is. When I google it I find many examples using this method, but I always see that they are using this method in a whole pure svg file. My svg elements are written in the aspx site, where I generate also html and svg code on server side.
Is that method working only in SVG Documents? Do I forget to include a library/ reference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you post some code it's easier to diagnose your problems. Take the relevant parts of your resulting svg/html.

Answer (score 1):

The [createSVGPoint method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff972165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you are refering to is probably a DOM element method that's available on the client side using ECMA script (javascript). It should be used in a client script block (in the aspx-page), you are probably trying to call it in the code behind (cs/vb code).

The svg-scripting reference is available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html). View the source of the resulting page and make sure that the svg markup is correct.

Comment: Im calling the method inside the svg/script/CDATA tag in my aspx page

Comment: I think I have the right markup. My situation is that i got a svg file, math.svg. It's working as expected. When I copy the whole code and paste it into my aspx page, it's not working properly. the only difference between the math.svg and SVG.aspx is that at the beginning of my aspx page is the line:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SVG.aspx.cs" Inherits="SVGTest.SVG" %>

Comment: If you open the SVG.aspx in your browser (via a webserver) and view the source. That should be identical to the working version. If not, then you know what to correct.

Comment: It is identical..It's just that while I'm running my application hosted in my Visual Studio's virtual webserver, on mouseover of the application it reports a problem, that createSVGPoint is not supported...

Comment: Same browser, same mime-type? Try accessing the svg file via the web server as well and see if that works as well.